# Can a Java applet function as a server?

Tags: java, applet, port, listen

Is it possible to write a Java applet that can be a server on the client machine within the client's local network?

To be more specific, what I am looking to do is tunnel non-web traffic over the web. The sender would send to the applet, which would then forward the received data back to the server.

Is this sort of thing possible? What are the restrictions that might get in the way?

<sub>Note: I know that the applet can connect back to the server, that isn't an issue. The issue is whether or not an applet can listen for a connection / data on a local, client-side port.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unsigned applet can only connect the host they come from.

A signed applet can do any connection you want and can listen on tcp-ip ports.

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: I'm not talking about calling out, I'm talking about listening for connections inbound on the local client machine. Forwarding that inbound data back down to the server the applet came from is not an issue as that is all done via HTTPS.

Comment: A signed applet can do about anything a java application can do, including listening on tcp-ip ports.

Comment: With an unsigned applet, will the user just be prompted to allow it if the applet tries to open a tcp-ip port to listen on, or will an exception get thrown?

Comment: This has changed over the years, browsers and JVM. I think (not 100% sure) that some old versions asked the user. I don't know today but an exception is probable. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Fantastic. As long as it's possible, having the applet be signed is the least of the issues :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Server does not connect to anywhere. Server opens server socket and is listening.

In past as far as I remember the server socket was restricted in MSIE and was permitted in Netscape (do you remember such browser?) :)

I personally have not been writing applets for the last 10 years, so I have no idea what happens now with currently existing browsers, but it is very easy to check. Just write the shortest applet you can and put code `new ServerSocket(1234).accept();` into its `init()` or `start()` method. If no exception was thrown you can write applet that functions as a server. Otherwise you cannot.

Just try it with all available browsers. 20 minutes work and you are done. Good luck. I'd will be glad to know about the results.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it cannot.

One reason why is that applets tend to be ran within security constrained environments, which means that they are denied the ability to open server sockets.

There are ways around such a restriction, basically you can specify a special security policy for the applet, or run it in a special unconstrained container; but why bother when you can just port the contents of your application into a standard servlet, or even a stand-alone server?

Comment: It can't be standalone or a standard servlet. It has to be as small as possible, since it will need to be loaded within a browser page. Other than that though, if it's a signed applet, then it can open a port on the local client and listen for in-bound connections?

Comment: Why is it so important to tunnel your information through someone else's computer?  You can tunnel it through your own computer!  Deploy a servlet on your computer, or run the stand-alone on your computer.  Have it listen to the non-web port, and relay the requests to the web port.  Web browsers make lousy servers.

Comment: This isn't for my own computer... it's a Java applet to allow others to tunnel data on non-web ports through the web back to our servers.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to have them setup ssl tunneling on a non-standard port.

Comment: That's the whole point... the end users are non-technical so the goal is to reduce the friction as much as possible. Setting up anything relating to any sort of networking is too much. Pointing the sending system to a specific address:port is about as complex as it can be.

Comment: And the sending system is a piece of hardware within the client network, so it's more than just a browser sending data.

Comment: Sounds like a solution crammed into a odd delivery network.  One close of the tab / browser and the whole thing will be lost.  If you really want ease of use, have a MSI install the thing, downloadable from the web link, embed your JVM to reduce "requirements" and launch the service with a post-install hook in the MSI.  Works pretty well, and I recommend WIX for the MSI packaging.

Comment: I agree that it's a strange solution, but any sort of install isn't allowed. Has to be web-only. Not my requirement, trust me.